# sql query to retrieve sum of contact records that match to one user with mysql and java

Tags: java, sql, select, foreign-keys

I have two table user and contact, each user can have multiple contacts 
I want to draw a graph (camembert) with JFreeChart(java library) to present the number of contacts that has each user
I tested :

```
select u.name, sum(c) from user u, contact c
```

but I have

```
unknown column c in field list
```

here are the structures of tables :

utilisateur = idutilisateur, identifiant, motdepasse, nom, prenom

contact = idcontact, ............, idutilisateur

How can I achieve that,

and also, please give me links to tutorials for learning to make queries like that because always I have this problem and I find only basic tutorials
thank you in advance

Comment: what columns are in the contact table?  Is ID a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the column of the table that you're trying to count, not just the table itself.

if you try:

```
select u.name, count(c.ID) 
from user u, contact c
```

You can count all records that have a value in the ID field.  If this is a primary key, then all records should have this field. Note the change from `sum` to `count`.

This won't fully solve your problem.  You also have to let sql know that the two tables are related by joining:

```
JOIN contact
ON user.ID=contact.userID
```

Put this after the `from user u` instead of `, contact c`

For a good start to learning sql, try here:  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
String sql1 = "SELECT u.nom, COUNT(c.idcontact) ContactsCount FROM utilisateur u LEFT " + "JOIN contact c ON u.idutilisateur = c.idutilisateur " + "GROUP BY u.nom";



sql = "SELECT u.nom + ' ' + u.prenom dd, COUNT(c.idcontact) FROM utilisateur u " + "LEFT OUTER JOIN contact c ON u.idutilisateur = c.idutilisateur GROUP BY u.nom + ' ' + u.prenom";
```

Comment: I test your suggestion : `String sql1 = "SELECT u.nom, COUNT(c.idcontact) ContactsCount FROM utilisateur u LEFT " +
     "JOIN contact c  u.idutilisateur = c.idutilisateur " +
     "GROUP BY u.nom";`  but I have this error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; `check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'u.idutilisateur = c.idutilisateur GROUP BY u.nom' at line 1`

Comment: What is `u.nom`? In OP is `u.name`.

Comment: Oh..., I missed `ON`. Edited.

Comment: please, see the question I edited it to tape structure of table, I used name and user only to translate to english

Comment: thank you? I forget ON, it works, also I want to put two attribute in one field for exemple u.nom+u.prenom and retrive the value with an space between them, I made String sql = `"SELECT u.nom + ' ' + u.prenom dd, COUNT(c.idcontact) FROM utilisateur u " +
     "INNER JOIN contact c ON u.idutilisateur = c.idutilisateur GROUP BY u.nom";` but it return zero record ?

Comment: See post, added new query. Your group condition is wrong. And also i suggest to use LEFT OUTER JOIN in case when you have users with no contacts. On this case query will exclude these users.

Comment: I tested the new query but the same problem, no error but no records

Comment: If you'd accept @mcalex solution,OK. If not, can you provide exact structure of your tables, test data and result data.

Comment: now I don't have problem with query, the query works, only when I use `u.nom + ' ' + u.prenom dd` it return no record, you see ?

Comment: Have you fixed also group by clause like this:`GROUP BY u.nom + ' ' + u.prenom`?

Comment: It only can be result of your `utilisateur` has no rows.

Comment: impossible, when I put 'u.nom' it be there, when I put 'u.nom + ' ' + u.prenom' no record, knowing that all 'utilisateu' have 'nom' and `prenom`

Comment: Try this: `SELECT nom + ' ' + prenom dd FROM utilisateur`. Does it returns any result?

Comment: it return 0, I don't know the cause

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23045/discussion-between-hamlet-hakobyan-and-simontifo)